# Delete from list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have this command that prints all combination without repetition:

```
    Grid[DeleteDuplicates[Map[Sort, Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 3]]]]
```

As a matter of fact the output is:

```
    a   a   a
    a   a   b
    a   a   c
    a   a   d
    a   b   b
    a   b   c
    a   b   d
    a   c   c
    a   c   d
    a   d   d
    b   b   b
    b   b   c
    b   b   d
    b   c   c
    b   c   d
    b   d   d
    c   c   c
    c   c   d
    c   d   d
    d   d   d
```

How can I delete the vectors wich have two o more 'b','c','d' ?

Comment: If you want to construct all orderless lists of length 3 from `{a,b,c,d}`, where any of `b,c,d` appear maximum once, there can be a simpler solution. E. g. `Map[PadLeft[#, 3, a]&, Subsets[{b, c, d}]]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I delete the vectors wich have two or more 'b','c','d' ?

```
 (lst = DeleteDuplicates[Map[Sort, Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 3]]]) // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Create the pattern to delete

```
 tst=Flatten[Permutations[{#,#,_},{3}]&/@{b,c,d},1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Delete them. I do not know now how to map/reset `DeleteCases`, so used a `Do`

```
 Do[lst= DeleteCases[lst,tst[[n]]],{n,1,Length@tst}]
 lst // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

```
Pick[lst, Max[Function[{x}, Count[#, x]] /@ {b, c, d}] <= 1 & /@ lst] // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** A variation on @Shadowray's suggestion to construct the desired list directly:

```
PadLeft[Subsets[{b, c, d}], Automatic, a]
(* or PadLeft[Subsets[{b, c, d}]] /. 0 -> a *)
```

> `{{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, d}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, d},{b, c, d}}`

**Update 2:** Also

```
 DeleteDuplicates@Subsets[{a, a, a, b, c, d}, {3}]
```

> `{{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, d}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a, c, d},{b, c, d}}`

Comment: +1 for the automatic creation of the list

Answer (score 5):

Here is a fairly clean approach.  By *naming* the pattern `b | c | d` (`|` is the short form of [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html)) we force a match for the same letter each time.

```
m = DeleteDuplicates[Map[Sort, Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 3]]];

m2 = DeleteCases[m, {___, x : b|c|d, x_, ___}]

m2 // Grid
```

$\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & a & a \\
 a & a & b \\
 a & a & c \\
 a & a & d \\
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & d \\
 a & c & d \\
 b & c & d \\
\end{array}$

Comment: @Wizard +1 for the nice approach. I adapted yours for the `OrderlessPatternSequence`

Answer (score 4):

```
m = DeleteDuplicates[Map[Sort, Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 3]]];

DeleteCases[m, {Alternatives@@Function[x, OrderlessPatternSequence[_, x, x],
Listable], {b, c, d}]}]

(*{{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, d}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a,c,d},{b, c, d}}*)

(* adopting Wizard's approach *)
DeleteCases[m, {OrderlessPatternSequence[x : b | c | d, x_, _] }] 
(*{{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, d}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a,c,d}, {b, c, d}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way to do it..

```
lst = Sort /@ Permutations[{b, c, d}, 3] // DeleteDuplicates
PadLeft[#, 3, a] & /@ lst
```

Comment: I realize my solution is similar to @shadowray but his solution is more clean than mine..

Answer (score 2):

And yet another method. Delete the a's from each sublist, and then check to see if Union will remove anything else:

```
In[1]:= list = DeleteDuplicates[Map[Sort, Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 3]]];

In[2]:= Select[list, 
 Length[Union[DeleteCases[#, a]]] == Length[DeleteCases[#, a]] &]

Out[2]= {{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, d}, {a, b, c}, {a, b,
   d}, {a, c, d}, {b, c, d}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
MapThread[Join, {Subsets[{a, a, a}] // Reverse, Subsets[{b, c, d}]}]
```

Out:

```
{{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, d}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a,
   c, d}, {b, c, d}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = DeleteDuplicates[Map[Sort, Tuples[{a, b, c, d}, 3]]];
```

Using [Fold](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html)

```
Fold[Pick[#1, LessThan[2] @* Count[#2] /@ #1] &, list, {b, c, d}]
```

{{a, a, a}, {a, a, b}, {a, a, c}, {a, a, d}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, d}, {a,
c, d}, {b, c, d}}